# mod_archive_odbc returns strange error on request

Tags: odbc, archive, ejabberd, mod-archive-odbc

I'm trying to install the mod_arhive_odbc module on an ejabberd server. Any time I make a request, I get this error. How can I resolve it?

```
 =ERROR REPORT==== 2013-08-21 17:59:09 ===
 E(<0.341.0>:gen_iq_handler:118) : {undef,
                                      [{ejabberd_config,get_myhosts,[]},
                                       {mod_archive_odbc,process_iq,3},
                                       {gen_iq_handler,process_iq,6},
                                       {gen_iq_handler,handle_info,2},
                                       {gen_server,handle_msg,5},
                                       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
```

Comment: mod_archive_odbc is a litle outdated, has you can see in [this link](http://endl.ch/content/mod_archive_odbc-release). Since you are using ODBC you will have an easier time with [mod_archive2](https://github.com/ndl/mod_archive2). You can get more data on mod_archive2 on [this page](http://endl.ch/content/modarchive2-status)

Comment: but mod_arhive2 is still under development and require ejabberd 3.x instead i used ejabberd 2.1.13

Comment: Would it be possible to trace the network activity from your ejabberd to the mysql DB? Also, with the mysql server details and credentials you're using, can you log in correctly manually?

Comment: @AlbertoPetrucci I ain't using any mod archive at the moment but I was pretty convinced I had used mod_archive2 with 2.1.X in the past... I will take a deeper look and get back to you if found something that may solve your problem

Comment: @AlbertoPetrucci you can see in [this link](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/2.1.x/src/ejabberd_config.erl) that the call **ejabberd_config:get_myhosts()** doesn't exist for the ejabberd 2.1.X branch although you can find it implemented on the [master branch](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd_config.erl), justifying the error.Where did you get that mod_archive_odbc? because the one present at [github](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/blob/2.1.x/mod_archive/src/mod_archive_odbc.erl) doesn't have the **ejabberd_config:get_myhosts()** call.

Comment: Thanks i solved the problem recompiling mod_archive_odbc (2.1.x)